# Post request error when sending "application/octet-stream" to an ASP.NET Core Web API service

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I need to create an ASP.NET Core 3 Web API that understand this URL

```
http://myapp.com/MyASPNetCore3WebApi/myController/myWebMethod?user=A0001
```

and one zipfile which goes as a content. This is the code that calls the needed API, which I need to create:

```
HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URI);
httpWebRequest.Timeout = -1;
httpWebRequest.KeepAlive = false;
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
httpWebRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/octet-stream";
httpWebRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;

Stream requestStream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
requestStream.Close();

HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

The code above is working fine, it is used everyday, sending data to a java web service, now I am replacing that system for a new one in ASP.NET Core and I can't change the caller's code, that's why I need to create a Web API that understand that URL.

I have wrote this code in my Web API, but I guess I am missing something that I can´t figure it out because I get an error ion the client (code above)

```
[HttpPost("myWebMethod")]
public FileStreamResult myWebMethod(string user, [FromBody]  Stream compress)
{
    byte[] zip = ((MemoryStream)compress).ToArray();
    byte[] data = ZipHelper.Uncompress(zip);
    .....................
}
```

The error I get in the client is this:-

> [System.Net.WebException] {"The remote server returned an error: (415)
> Unsupported Media Type."} System.Net.WebException

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: This error is caused by `FromBody` attribute at it expects `application/json` content type.

Comment: Hi, please tell me, what can I do, ? I don´t have a clue

Answer (score 3):

If the goal is to read the raw request content, this can be done using [`HttpContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.httpcontext) controller property. `HttpContext` has [`Request`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontext.request) property that provides access to the actual HTTP request.
No additional model properties or controller arguments are needed to access raw request stream. It's important to note that `FromBody` and `FromForm` binding should not be used in this case.

---

There are couple notes regarding the code in the example from the original question.

> byte[] zip = ((MemoryStream)compress).ToArray();
>
> byte[] data = ZipHelper.Uncompress(zip);

1. The `HttpContext.Request.Body` property does not return `MemoryStream`, it returns its own implementation of a `Stream`. It means that there is no `ToArray` method.
2. When reading the entire content of a request directly into the server's memory, it is better to check the content length, otherwise the client can crash the server by sending a large enough request.
3. Using *Async methods when reading the content of the request will improve performance.